# What is the meaning of the blue circle with exclamation mark overlaid on project icon in solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, solution-explorer

I'm not talking about the source control icons, but the blue overlaid icon on the right.

[image]

Comment: Is there a "resolve errors" option in the context menu, or any tooltip when hovered over?

Comment: There wasn't anything, no. Now it's disappeared (restart?) so I'll probably never know why.

Comment: That's one of those cases where I miss the old style written\printed manuals ;-)

Comment: It is still there on VS2022. Unloading and reloading the project removed the mark from any marked project, though.

Comment: Hi @HaymoKutschbach, I tried your solution but it didn't work, do you have any other suggestions? I'm on VS2022.

Answer (score 2):

It means there is an alert for the project. If you hover over the icon you get the Source Control tooltip ("Checked In" in the other answer), but if you hover over the title of the project you will get a tooltip with the alert.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for reference as I was looking, I am just converting a solution to a later project and what it appears to mean is that the blue dotted project will produce no output for the current configuration - ie, you are currently building a debug x86 build but there is only a configuration for x64 or release.
In the .net8 build I was doing it lacked a list of configurations:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms> <--
    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations> <--
</PropertyGroup>
```

so that even though it has separate entries for those project types later on, it wasn't using it.

If you look in the project output you will see that the project was skipped:

> ========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 2 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0):

I still see that icon and really with a tooltip:
[overlay icon with tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcUc4.png)

Comment: This is the same tooltip you should find on your other projects, at least it is for me. So the tooltip appears irrelevant to the icon (which leaves the question unanswered unfortunately as I haven't any clue either)